# Virtual Box VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).. Hyper V and core isolation is disabled

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running windows 10 enterprise trying to launch a VM in Virtualbox and it fails with the error. 
"VMMR0_DO_NEM_INIT_VM failed: VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2 (VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2).
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)."

[image: Vbox Error Outut]

I have HyperV disabled in windows features and core isolation turned off
[image: Windows settings]

I've checked the registry as well and core isolation / memory itegrity is off there.  I've also made sure that in group policy settings that virtualization based security is disabled.

My BIOS does have VT-X /VT-D enabled.

I'm currently on Virtual box 6.1.6 but have tried previous versions back to 6.0.12 with no success.

Answer (score 48):

This happens to me from time to time on my Windows 10 host. I tried a lot of things to fix it, but what worked in the end is running this command as an administer in PowerShell:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and rebooting the computer.

Comment: I turned off anything I could turn off and restored whatever I could restore, but my poor vbox just refused to work, until I tried your command. Thank you very much.

Comment: just incase anyone is looking to revert this change back the command is "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--set#hypervisor-settings

Comment: The VT-x error showed up for me as well after docker installation (and uninstall). The first thing I tried was this solution and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I got this error too. I got passed it by uninstalling VirtualBox, removing any residual files, and then reinstalling VirtualBox.

Based on Google search results of this error, posts about it started appearing only a few days ago. I found out how to get passed this error from one of the comments on https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/g4hksf/virtualbox_problems/.

By the way, the only Windows feature that needs to be turned off is HyperV.

Comment: After uninstalling virtual box in control panel, doesn't VirtualbBox get fully removed?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Tried the turning the HyperV off and rebooting but that did not work.  My BIOS had Virtural turned on too.  What fixed it for me was to go into BIOS, turn the virtual off then reboot it.  Then reboot again and go back into the BIOS and turn virtual back on.

Comment: I've tried all of the other suggested solutions, and eventually only this helped

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and simply enabling BIOS VT-x was enabled, but simply enabling again BIOS VT-x got rid of the error. Uninstall virtual box, delete Virtual box files in program files, and in ProgramData

In windows 10

Settings-> Update & security->Recovery -> Advanced startup ->Restart now

Next after restarting choose
Troubleshoot ->Advanced options->UEFI Firmware Settings ->click Restart

Then select F10 ->System configurations->Virtualization Technology select enabled and pressed enter
Exit Saving changes->Select yes

Then reinstall virtual box, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps [here](https://www.minitool.com/news/vt-x-is-not-available.html) (like you did) and nothing worked.

Eventually, I disabled `VT-d` in my BIOS, and suddenly I was able to run VirtualBox machines. I have no idea why it worked, just try it if you have nothing else to do.

Answer (score 0):

I did all the steps I found on the Internet, but I solved the problem by installing virtualbox version 7. The previous version was version 5 and my windows version is 10

Answer (score -1):

This happend with me when windows 10 updated to windows 2004

So to fix this Make sure you disable the feature  HyperV of windows feature

start -> Windows Features ->  Windows Hypervisor Platform -> uncheck if checked.

restart your PC.

then try `vagrant up` or start the virtualbox machine again

[image]